# Increase the volume of Amazon Sagemaker Training and Evaluation jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I am running a Sagemaker pipeline with custom container for training and evaluation. The training container will train the model by downloading the data from the S3 bucket, and store the model into a S3 bucket, the evaluation container will get that model, download the test data from the S3 bucket and prepare the evaluation results. Currently the training data is downloaded in the container itself. The code is working correctly but with huge data I am getting the following error: `OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`. I am thinking of attaching an EBS volume so that training data could be downloaded in the EBS volume and we can get away with the error.
Anyone has implemented similar solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you kick of the job using [CreateTrainingJob](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTrainingJob.html) API you can set the volume size in GB:

```
 "ResourceConfig": { 
      "InstanceCount": number,
      "InstanceGroups": [ 
         { 
            "InstanceCount": number,
            "InstanceGroupName": "string",
            "InstanceType": "string"
      ...
      "VolumeSizeInGB": number
   }
```

If you are using:

Boto3: [create_training_job](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker/client/create_training_job.html)

```
 ResourceConfig={
        'InstanceType': 'ml.m4.xlarge'|'ml.m4.2xlarge'|'ml.m4.4xlarge'|'ml.m4.10xlarge'|'ml.m4.16xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.2xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.4xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.8xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.12xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.16xlarge'|'ml.m5.large'|'ml.m5.xlarge'|'ml.m5.2xlarge'|'ml.m5.4xlarge'|'ml.m5.12xlarge'|'ml.m5.24xlarge'|'ml.c4.xlarge'|'ml.c4.2xlarge'|'ml.c4.4xlarge'|'ml.c4.8xlarge'|'ml.p2.xlarge'|'ml.p2.8xlarge'|'ml.p2.16xlarge'|'ml.p3.2xlarge'|'ml.p3.8xlarge'|'ml.p3.16xlarge'|'ml.p3dn.24xlarge'|'ml.p4d.24xlarge'|'ml.p4de.24xlarge'|'ml.p5.48xlarge'|'ml.c5.xlarge'|'ml.c5.2xlarge'|'ml.c5.4xlarge'|'ml.c5.9xlarge'|'ml.c5.18xlarge'|'ml.c5n.xlarge'|'ml.c5n.2xlarge'|'ml.c5n.4xlarge'|'ml.c5n.9xlarge'|'ml.c5n.18xlarge'|'ml.g5.xlarge'|'ml.g5.2xlarge'|'ml.g5.4xlarge'|'ml.g5.8xlarge'|'ml.g5.16xlarge'|'ml.g5.12xlarge'|'ml.g5.24xlarge'|'ml.g5.48xlarge'|'ml.trn1.2xlarge'|'ml.trn1.32xlarge'|'ml.trn1n.32xlarge'|'ml.m6i.large'|'ml.m6i.xlarge'|'ml.m6i.2xlarge'|'ml.m6i.4xlarge'|'ml.m6i.8xlarge'|'ml.m6i.12xlarge'|'ml.m6i.16xlarge'|'ml.m6i.24xlarge'|'ml.m6i.32xlarge'|'ml.c6i.xlarge'|'ml.c6i.2xlarge'|'ml.c6i.8xlarge'|'ml.c6i.4xlarge'|'ml.c6i.12xlarge'|'ml.c6i.16xlarge'|'ml.c6i.24xlarge'|'ml.c6i.32xlarge',
        'InstanceCount': 123,
        'VolumeSizeInGB': 123,
        'VolumeKmsKeyId': 'string',
        'KeepAlivePeriodInSeconds': 123,
       ...
    },
```

PySDK: [volume_size](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html)

```
sagemaker.estimator.EstimatorBase(...,volume_size=30,...)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented the same by following PySDK method. Now I am getting the following error:
"""
sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR    Reporting training FAILURE;
sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR    ExecuteUserScriptError:;

ExitCode -9;
ErrorMessage "";
Command "/usr/local/bin/python train.py";
sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR Encountered exit_code 1;"""

The train.py is the entry point of the code.